# How is abnormal Driver termination handled for a Spark App in Yarn cluster mode

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-emr

We're using AWS EMR for our spark jobs. All our jobs are submitted in yarn cluster mode, so the driver will run in one of the cluster nodes. We use on-demand node for master, and spot-instances for the core nodes. Now, although we almost always choose instances with < 5% interruption rate, sometimes it so happens that a significant fraction of our cluster nodes get terminated prematurely (probably because of higher demands).

So, I was wondering, in the above situation, what happens if a node containing the driver process goes down? Is there any chance of recovery for the spark job in that case? Or is the job gone forever?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Spark driver is a single point of failure because it holds all cluster state for the running App.

In practice non-ephemeral storage can be used for check-pointing batch Apps after expensive expensive transformations. That said, trying to re-start after such a situation can be done, but when I looked into it, it is quite difficult to say the least. I asked such a question under my name some time ago, you can find it. I am quite technical but felt: gosh what a lot of hard work.

So, the recovery means rolling your own stuff, or accepting a re-run. Since I last evaluated EMR I see that the driver can run on the Master and that can be failed-over, but that is not the same thing as far as I can see, nor what you wish.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the insights. I'm not actually averse to running the driver on EMR master, just that we never gave it a serious thought. I think choosing an on-demand or spot-block instance for driver is a viable option. In that case, I assume the job has to be run on yarn client mode. What are your thoughts on that?

Comment: I am not so sure, as if Driver fails it may fail on the other machine as well. That's why I stated the "not the same thing". My impression is it remains a single point of failure in all cases.

Comment: Something like ORACLE RAC just works differently with coordinators and heart beats.

Comment: I agree, that it's a single point of failure. But choosing to run it on a non-spot instance would atleast guard against the instance-termination failure, am I right? Although there might be other issues coming from the yarn client mode that I'm not aware of.

Comment: Oh absolutely. But still a single point of failure for the currently running Driver. My first statement here.

Comment: That was a case of penny-wise pound foolish!!! dare I say it.

Answer (score 0):

EMR has node leveling for CORE nodes in Yarn. Your spark driver/ Application master only gets created in CORE nodes. And HDFS also resides in CORE nodes only.
So to handle your situation in a best way, you may consider to use both CORE and TASK group.
What you can do to tackle this -

1. MASTER: On-demand
2. CORE: On-demand. Minimum no of Instances can be 1.
3. TASK: Spot with autoscaling with minimal EBS volume. Minimum no of Instances can be 0 this case.

This will reduce your cost also ensure that node containing the driver process never goes down.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-master-core-task-nodes.html

Comment: thanks. Actually it's not possible for us to have only one core node because of sizable data write to hdfs (which then gets copied to s3 via s3-dist-cp), and therin lies the problem.

Comment: Add auto scaling too for CORE nodes. If this possible. Another possible option to use EMRFS instead of HDFS as you are ultimately writes data to S3.